# Stop the process listening in port 80

Tags: windows-7, iis-7

IIS is listening port 80. I can't stop. I tried all possible methods.

- Stopped World Wide Web publishing service.
- Stopped IIS.

Nothing helps. PID 4 always uses port 80 according to netstat: http://prntscr.com/2fw0c

Running windows 7 x64

Comment: and pid 4 is what process?

Comment: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430141/port-80-is-being-used-by-system-pid-4-what-is-that
 - Hope it helps

Comment: system.. i think it's IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it is IIS? It could be the Microsoft Web Deployment Service

Take a look at [can-the-web-deploy-agent-run-on-a-port-other-than-80-on-iis6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867392/can-the-web-deploy-agent-run-on-a-port-other-than-80-on-iis6)

Answer (score 1):

Not a programming question, but I will bite.

Sometimes processes can become "orphaned".  When they are in this state, they will hold all systems resources open (file handles, sockets, etc.)  The only way to release the resources is to reboot the machine.

Have you verified that the IIS process is killed on the machine?  If it is, but NETSTAT -ao is still reporting that PID 4 has port 80, it is an orphaned process and the machine will require a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP.SYS is the kernel-mode listener for HTTP traffic, and if PID 4 is listening, that's probably HTTP.SYS.

IIS isn't the only consumer of HTTP.SYS - any process can register a URL namespace (eg, http://*:80/yourapphere), and HTTP.SYS will leave the port bound and ready to receive requests for that app.

PID 4 being the System 'process' is correct, because HTTP.SYS is a k-mode component, not a user-mode process.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling all services using port 80 it may still show as active because of the HTTP.sys.

To turn off go to registry:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP**

Set **Start** value to 4.

Restart Computer